# How to get result from on activity result method to Shared preferences

Tags: android

I am beginner to android...in qr scanner after click on button it will scan 
 and displaying result in activity..I want to get that displayed result        to shared preferences..can anyone help me

below is my code

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_screen);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    customerSno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanContent);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IHomeActivity.class);

           startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

private void setCustomerSerialNName(String s) {

String customerSNo = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.getString("customerSNo", "null");

SharedPreferences.Editor editor =IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("customerSNo",s);

    //editor.putString("customerPass", passcode);
    if (customerSNo.equals(s)) {
    } else {
        editor.putBoolean("custSNoAuthStatus", false);
    }
    editor.commit();
    LightManager.LightOp lightOp = new LightManager.LightOp();
    lightOp.setToWWWMode();
}





public void scanMarginScanner(View view) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(SmallCaptureActivity.class);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        String scanContent = result.getContents();
        customerSno.setText(" " + scanContent);


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is customerSno ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to save your number into SharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefName", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("myPrefNumVarName", myPrefNumVarValue);
    editor.commit();
```

Then read your saved value:

```
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String myValue = sp.getString("myPrefNumVarName", "none"); // second string is the return, used when nothing is returned from the first string
```

This solution saves the value as Int and reads as String, and this may not be what you want, can easily be reconfigured for your needs, though.

Comment: @pruthvi v reddy please check as correct the answer if it solved your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want result in onActivityResult then you have to call

```
startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
```

in Caller Activity and add code in calling activity:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("key", value);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

and finish the calling activity

and in onActivityResult method :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == request_code){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           String value =  data.getExtras().getString("key");
        }
    }

}
```